# Cannot select from the MySQL view with EF

Tags: c#, mysql, view, orm, entity-framework-6

I had a complex view joining a couple of tables but it freezed my C# app so I simplified it in order to get it to work, however it still freezes and I dont have a clue why.

I have a table called 'admittances' containing: AdmittanceID, Number, Date, Notes.

I created a view which selects three of those: AdmittanceID as ID, Number as Number and Date as Date.

In a database it just works, no big deal. I mapped it via 'Update model from database' option in a model wizard inside C# EF model and it shows up as an entity with three columns and entity key column 'ID'.

However while trying to loop over all the records the program stops working and does not go any further (in debugging it just does not pass through the loop).

```
meraserwEntities db = new meraserwEntities();

var myQuery = db.clientstodevices.ToList();

//Tried also other versions that are listed below

var myQuery = from d in db.clientstodevices select d;

foreach (var item in myQuery)
{
    ClientsToDevices.Add(item);
}

// Or without loop - then it freezed exactly in this line

ClientsToDevices = db.clientstodevices.ToList();
```

Please help, tried everything ..

Comment: "In a database it just works, no big deal". Does that mean that  queries in workbench perform well?

Comment: @GertArnold exactly. And if I run the query (view) in workbench it selects desired records.

Comment: Is the view really unique over these three columns? And what happens if you do `FirstOrDefault()`, or `Take(1)`?

Comment: If I do a query over this view it works, but only after trying to add this to a BindableCollection and converting to the clientstodevice object it freezes.

First code works, the rest does not

`var myQuery = from d in db.clientstodevices select d;
 myQuery.Take(1);
`


`var myQuery = from d in db.clientstodevices select d;
 clientstodevice myItem = (clientstodevice)myQuery.Take(1);
 clientstodevice myItem = (clientstodevice)myQuery.FirstOrDeafult();

foreach (clientstodevice item in myQuery)
            {
                ClientsToDevices.Add(item);
            }
`

Comment: @GertArnold what do you mean by 'unique over these three columns'?
I have added a column containing row number so as to avoid having exactly the same data in one record.

Comment: I mean, you don't show the unique key that a view is supposed to have when mapped in EF6. I thought the three columns comprised this unique key. It's hard to tell anything more about the issue, not seeing the tables, the view definition and the mapped class.